# Angularjs: Is there a way to create a timeDate object from a user selected timezone?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, debugging, datetime, timezone

> Timezones
>
> Keep in mind that Angular datetime filter uses the time zone settings of the browser. So the same application will show different time information depending on the time zone settings of the computer that the application is running on. Neither Javascript nor Angular currently supports displaying the date with a timezone specified by the developer.

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<p>Using var birthday: {{birthday}}!</p>
<p>Using custom filter date: {{birthday| date}}!</p>
<p>You were born at {{birthday|date:'shortTime' }} on {{birthday|date:'mediumDate' }}!</p>
<br />Enter your birthday1:
<br />
<input ng-model="birthday" size="60" />
</div>
```

My internationalized app needs three separate inputs which will  be sent to a server for further processing: a date, a time and a time zone. In my current fiddle, the user has to type all three values in the same input field in order to maintain the intended data binding. As soon as I try to separate the values, I loose the data binding. Is this expected Anguarjs behaviour?
http://jsfiddle.net/gogirl/JmYT4/
And the more advanced:
http://jsfiddle.net/gogirl/7cWbG/

Is there a way to create a timeDate object from a user selected timezone? As I am new to angularjs i may be going about this the wrong way. If there are any existing directives that get me half there please advise. The comments here http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:date  have helped me a lot but also points to a need of making this simpler for developers and I'd like to help.

Answer (score 0):

Use the full syntax of the [Date Time string format](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es5#sec-15.9.1.15):

```
 var foo = Date.parse("1996-09-13T12:00:00.000+05:00");
 var bar = new Date(foo);
 var baz = bar.toUTCString();
```

**References**

- [Date and Time Formats](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime)